# Rails -- use RSpec "get" and "response" methods in Rake task

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rake, rake-task

I know RSpec has useful methods "get" and "response.should" to run integration tests - I want to know how I can use these (or other methods to achieve the same result) in a Rake task:

```
desc "Check all content items with type 0 and do something"
task :my_task => :environment do
    ContentItem.where("content_type = ?", 0).each do |obj|
        get "/my_path/"+obj.value
        if (response has a certain html tag)
            perform some action on obj
        end        
    end
end
```

I know that I can't just run rspec methods like that, but this is effectively what I need to do, and I need to be able to process information returned when /my_path/obj.value is opened.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

why do you need to go through the url to do this action with your ContentItem ? Why not just use the local obj and do stuff?

Basically it looks like you're mixing up view-code with model code here... the model's object should not depend on values in the html... if there is some information being figured out in the view... put it into a method on the ContentItem *model* and call that code either from the view... or from this rake task.

Edit:
Ok.... well if you really need to GET a URL - look into Ruby's Net::Http gem - that will literally fetch URLs. Rails doesn't do that as standard... even for local URLs.

You might then be able to use a parser such as hpricot or nokogiri to parse the results to find the tag you need.

Comment: I agree Taryn that would be ideal -- The problem is that the information is being figured out in the view so I can't move it to the model.  Basically there are websites that sometimes frame-bust when we try to load them in a frame on our site, and we are trying to keep a database record of whether or not the remote url has frame busting enabled (that's what this rake task is supposed to do) so that we don't attempt to load them if they have busting.

Comment: So I am trying to run a rake task that basically runs a GET http request for the page that attempts to frame the url, and then if the frame was busted mark it in the database.

Comment: OK - I've added an edit that gives you some example gems that could help you on your way. Good luck - sounds like it might be tricky because even net::http might not actually trigger a frame-bust. I don't know how that would actually manifest for you. But at least it's a start :)

Comment: I tried using net::http and it did successfully access the page, but as you predicted no frame-bust was triggered.  Any ideas on how to resolve it?  I don't think a parser like Nokogiri will do the trick unfortunately.

Comment: Sadly no. I'm guessing that only a *real* browser will do what you want.

hmmm...I know there are testing-frameworks that fire up a real browser (Watir springs to mind) and you could write an automated test using one of those - though it will have to all be applicable in a browser window. Eg "navigate to URL x, if the frame busts (not sure how you'd test that) then naviagte to url Y and enter these values and hit submit" Where URL Y is a form that will cause the db changes that you want.